# AWS NodeJS TypeScript SDK V3 DynamoDB PutItemCommand - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Tags: typescript, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am building an application that manages information about different media such as videos, images, etc. The app uses a DynamoDB for storing the information and I use the TypeScript AWS SDK to connect to the database.

I am currently coding the part for storing information related to videos but I am having trouble when trying to insert an object in the DynamoDB table and I am using this code to do it:

```
import { DynamoDBClient, PutItemCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb';
import { APIGatewayProxyEvent, APIGatewayProxyResult } from 'aws-lambda';
import { DynamoDBDocumentClient } from '@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb';

export async function postVideo(
    event: APIGatewayProxyEvent,
    ddbClient: DynamoDBClient
): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> {
    const ddbDocClient = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(ddbClient);

    const item = JSON.parse(event.body!);

    const currentDateTime = new Date().toISOString();
    const pk = `VIDEO`;
    const sk = `${item.owner}#${item.title}#${currentDateTime}`;
    item.PK = pk;
    item.SK = sk;

    const result = await ddbDocClient.send(
        new PutItemCommand({
            TableName: process.env.TABLE_NAME,
            Item: item,
        })
    );
    console.log(result);

    return {
        statusCode: 201,
        body: JSON.stringify({ PK: pk, SK: sk }),
    };
}
```

I know that when using the DynamoDBClient I need to specify the type of each of the fields of the item, so I decided to use the DynamoDBDocumentClient instead of directly using the DynamoDBClient in order to not have to marshall-unmarshall, but when I try to insert the item in the database, it throws a TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0').

When trying to insert the item, it contains something like this:

```
{
  owner: "Test",
  title: "Test",
  description: "Test",
  link: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ",
  PK: "VIDEO",
  SK: "Test#Test#2023-06-20T17:20:59.683Z",
}
```

I don't know if I am missing something here. My guess is that it isn't getting the types of the item correctly but I thought it was supossed to get them directly from the JS object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're using the `DynamoDBDocumentClient` you need to use `PutCommand` from `"@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb"`, instead of `PutItemCommand` from `@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb`.

Use this import instead:

```
import { PutCommand } from "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb";
```

This is slop on Amazon's part, IMO. There should only be one set of commands, but I guess it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem today using the v3 SDK. This example demonstrates defining types for each value. Following it solved the problem for me:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-table-read-write.html

Does not work:

```
const item = {
  key: 'my-key',
  value: 'my-value'
}
```

Works:

```
const item = {
  key: { 'S': 'my-key' },
  value: { 'S': 'my-value' }  
}
```

Comment: Nobody wants to or should have to do that. Do you know of any way to do this without specifying the types?

Comment: Use the `marshall` function from "@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb" to convert a regular object to DynamoDB's horrific syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is not one from DynamoDB, but from your code logic itself. My advice is to ensure you are parsing the event object correctly.

```
console.log(event);
const item = JSON.parse(event.body!);
console.log(typeof(item))
console.log(item);
```

Adding these log statements should give you enough information to overcome your issue.

Comment: I debugged both with console logs and VS Code debugger. item is of type object and the object seems correct to me. I have read other posts talking about how you have to specify the type of each attribute of the item for DynamoDB to understand it, but I though it wasn't the case with DynamoDBDocumentClient

Comment: Your issue is not with DynamoDB, it's a JavaScript exception you are getting. Remove the API call to DynamoDB and try invoke the function to see if it succeeds.

Comment: I tried, the problem occurs when I make the call to DynamoDB. If I comment the ddbDocClient.send(new PutItemCommand({...}) the function correctly returns the 201 code and the body with the PK and SK.